# L2TP connection not working with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, l2tp

At some point (didn't catch exactly when) My L2TP VPN stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04.
Here is the journactl output

```
apr 07 19:14:35 GS66 NetworkManager[312934]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 NetworkManager[312931]: Starting strongSwan 5.8.2 IPsec [starter]...
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 NetworkManager[312931]: Loading config setup
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 NetworkManager[312931]: Loading conn 'b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 ipsec_starter[312931]: Starting strongSwan 5.8.2 IPsec [starter]...
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 ipsec_starter[312931]: Loading config setup
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 ipsec_starter[312931]: Loading conn 'b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 ipsec_starter[312948]: Attempting to start charon...
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.11.0-27-generic, x86_64)
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 ipsec_starter[312948]: charon (312949) started after 40 ms
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a'
apr 07 19:14:37 GS66 charon[312949]: 05[CFG] added configuration 'b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a'
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 07[CFG] rereading secrets
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 07[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 07[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 07[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 09[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a'
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 11[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a[1] to X.Y.X.Y
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 11[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a[1] to X.Y.X.Y
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 11[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
apr 07 19:14:38 GS66 charon[312949]: 11[NET] sending packet: from 127.0.0.1[500] to X.Y.X.Y[500] (532 bytes)
apr 07 19:14:42 GS66 charon[312949]: 12[IKE] sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
apr 07 19:14:42 GS66 charon[312949]: 12[NET] sending packet: from 127.0.0.1[500] to X.Y.X.Y[500] (532 bytes)
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[313076]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 charon[312949]: 00[IKE] destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a[1] to X.Y.X.Y
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: sending packet: from 127.0.0.1[500] to X.Y.X.Y[500] (532 bytes)
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: sending retransmit 1 of request message ID 0, seq 1
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: sending packet: from 127.0.0.1[500] to X.Y.X.Y[500] (532 bytes)
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: destroying IKE_SA in state CONNECTING without notification
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 NetworkManager[312978]: establishing connection 'b7b9df74-4fbf-408c-bd6e-91dcd1787e3a' failed
apr 07 19:14:48 GS66 ipsec_starter[312948]: child 312949 (charon) has quit (exit code 0)
```

I've looked through internet and can't find a valid solution. I've reinstalled networkmanager-lt2p plugin, no luck.

The curious thing that I noticed after comparing output with VM where the VPN connection was working, was the address that packets were sent from.

It seems that packets are being set **from 127.0.0.1** which is odd (in all other environments the IPs are from network interfaces not loopback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had something wrong with my routes table. The lo interface had the biggest priority and was default route, leading to VPN connection trying to use that. Since the message didn't go beyond my computer (because 127.0.0.1  doesn't go beyond PC), I was not able to connect to VPN

Solution was to modify the routes table to have a bigger priority to my local IP route and set it as the default